# How to Replace Shutdown command with Switch User+Monitor off

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, logoff

When I click on shutdown on start menu, I want my Windows 8.1 computer to do:

1- Switch User (As long as lock keeps computer going on with normal power, while executables are running, it's also desirable.).

2- Turn off monitor

**Note:** Shutdown button has to remain with the same name.

I've tried several gpedit.msc and regedit tweaks without luck.
Things I tried on GPEDIT.MSC:

1- Users Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar > Change start menu power button(This tweak only changes the default power mode you see when you first alt-f4)

2- There's another tweak - Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands - which is not what I wanted.

Edit: Actually I'm trying to change the behaviour of "Shutdown" command anywhere, either on start menu or when you ALT-F4.

I need shutdown not to shut down the computer, basicly.

Comment: Switch User...or lock? If the former, what user do you want to switch to?

Comment: Which gpedit and regedit "tweaks" have your tried? Plus what Twisty said. I assume you mean you want to either log off or lock.

Comment: I've edited my question with those info.